# parse nested JSON using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i want to get the "Name" value (i.e xyz,abc,mno,mxc) from the json data, but as the parent node ids are different i am not able to parse it ..??

```
"all": {
    "id55": {
        "Tid": "1",
        "Name": "xyz",
        "TypeName": "author"
    },
    "id56": {
        "Tid": "2",
        "Name": "abc",
        "TypeName": "author"
    },
    "id57": {
        "Tid": "3",
        "Name": "mno",
        "TypeName": "author"
    },
    "id58": {
        "Tid": "4",
        "Name": "mzc",
        "TypeName": "author"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** to iterate over your object and get `Name` value:

```
$.each(all, function(i,val) {
   console.log(all[i].Name);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8LjC/)**

Answer (score 3):

```
var all = {
            "id55": {
                "Tid": "1",
                "Name": "xyz",
                "TypeName": "author"
            },
            "id56": {
                "Tid": "2",
                "Name": "abc",
                "TypeName": "author"
            },
            "id57": {
                "Tid": "3",
                "Name": "mno",
                "TypeName": "author"
            },
            "id58": {
                "Tid": "4",
                "Name": "mzc",
                "TypeName": "author"
            }
        }
for (var a in all) {
  console.log(all[a].Name);
}
```

**output**

```
xyz
abc
mno
mzc
```

Comment: aww hate it when that happens :)